# How do I setup a group in Google Apps for Business to be able to send to to all employees via one email address?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I am running Google Apps for Business for managing our organization emails.

I want to setup an email such as `team@mycompany.com` and when sending an email to this email address, all team members will get the email in the same time.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create an organisation-wide group from your Google Apps control panel:

> Here's how to create an organization-wide group:
>
> 1. Create a new group. [Learn more](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33343)
> 2. On the "Create a new group" page, click Add all users within [organization name] to this group.
>
> The group's member list now includes a special member called All users
>   within organization name.
>
> You can edit the groups access settings or delete it, just like any
>   other group. However, you can't edit the members within the All users
>   member.
>
> Tip: To prevent spam being sent to everyone in your domain, allow only
>   group owners and managers to send messages to a group that has the All
>   users member.

Quoted from Apps Administration Help, [here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66338&topic=25840&ctx=topic).

Comment: Ok, I've done it, but every time a user replies the e-mail, he/she receives error notification. I would like to allow them autoreply to message author or group manager, but how?

Answer (score 1):

You should allow external users to send email to the group address.

There is an option for that when creating the group.

Comment: A little more explanation as to how to do this would be nice.